# Error - Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value

Tags: swift

So I have this custom struct

```
public struct Feature {
    var featureID: String = ""
    var featureName: String = ""
    var matchingFieldValue: String = ""

    var polygonCollection =  [MyPolygon]()

    mutating func setFeatureID(featureID: String) {
        self.featureID = featureID
    }

    func getMatchingFieldValue() -> String {
        return matchingFieldValue
    }

    mutating func setMatchingFieldvalue(matchingFieldValue: String) {
        self.matchingFieldValue = matchingFieldValue
    }

    public func getPolygonCollection() -> [MyPolygon] {
         return polygonCollection  
    }  
}
```

and I am trying to append a polygon to my polygonCollection by calling this function

```
feature.getPolygonCollection().append(polygon)
```

but I am getting the error

`cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value`

by the way, I am defining the polygon in another class, it is a long class so just put the relevant calling code that gives the error.

All the previously asked ques

I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to value semantics `getPolygonCollection()` returns an immutable copy of `polygonCollection`. You cannot change it. That's what the error message says.

Add this function **in** the struct

```
mutating func add(polygon: MyPolygon) {
    self.polygonCollection.append(polygon)
}
```

and call it

```
feature.add(polygon)
```